# View is not working the intended way

Tags: views, nodes

I created a view and set it as in the following screenshots.

> [image: screenshot]

> [[image]

If (under the *Format* section) I select *Show:Content* or any other setting, I can see the view being displayed on page and on the preview like I want it to show; if I select *Show:Fields*, the view doesn't show on page, but it does show on the preview.

To clarify the *it shows on page* part:

- The theme is the right one
- The region is defined on that particular theme, and I can display content on that region besides the one I really want to show, which also dismisses block settings preventing it from showing

Why is this happening? What can I do to make the view show on page when selecting the *Show:Fields* option?

Since I am a Drupal beginner, I don't know if the issue is merely caused from a wrong value I set for one or more settings.

Comment: could you export your view and past here, or if you're not sure how to do that, screenshot the view UI

Comment: can you expand the "Advanced" section in the right column and replace screenshot?  chances are- you have a contextual filter applied to the view and would only be able to see the preview results if you pass an argument.

Comment: Did you assign it under the right theme? Does the block have any settings on it preventing it from displaying? Is the region being printed in the theme? Also, what does `I select something like Show:Content` mean?

Comment: So, about the last question Kevin, in one of the screenshots you can see (under the Format field) the Show option, which is now set to Show Fields. If I select any other option, the content shows on page. That also answers some of the other questions : Right theme? Yes. Printed in the theme?When other options are selected. Something preventing block from displaying? No.

Comment: So the question went to [closed] .. Can anybody explain me what I need to do so that it becomes clear what the issue/question is? I really need a answer on this .. @Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a clear cache solves the issue.  Don't know if yours is the same issue but it happened to me and i cleared cache and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Tried your solution and it didn't work. Thank you for your time though.